# How to get a mask bit from two inputs with python?

Tags: python

The program takes an begin IP address and an End IP Address as input and gives the following information about the inputs:

(Mask Bits )

Example : 5.23.112.0          5.23.119.255

Answer (score 0):

*you can try this one*

```
ip1 = ''.join([bin(int(x)+256)[3:] for x in ip1.split('.')])
ip2 = ''.join([bin(int(x)+256)[3:] for x in ip2.split('.')])
count = 0
for i in xrange(len(ip1)):
    if ip1[i] == ip2[i]:
        count+=1
    else:
        break
mask_bits = '0' * count + '1' * (len(ip1) - count)
```